# What is the equivalent of `data[] = $var` for an object?

Tags: php, oop, loops

I'm looping through a mysql query and storing the values to an object.  I want to automatically iterate the object like one would an array as I store the data to it.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $query->result() as $row )
{
    $data->$i = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

I'd like to mimic the code below, but for an object, removing the need for `$i` in the above code:

```
foreach( $query->result() as $row )
    $data[] = $row;
```

What is the equivalent to `$data[] = $row` to iterate an object as you store variables to it in a foreach or while loop?

NOTE: It's clear that I shouldn't be using objects in this manner.  Could you please elaborate on why this is the case?

Comment: This sounds like an inappropriate use of PHP to me. Why not just store them in an array in the object? Like `$data -> results[]`?

Comment: What are you trying to 'gain' by doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one, because objects don't work that way. Besides, if you want to store things in a linear fashion then you shouldn't be using an object in that manner regardless.

Comment: uh oh.  could you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Not much to elaborate on. It all boils down to "don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an object you can iterate using `foreach()` it has to implement the iterator-interface, cf. http://php.net/iterator

Answer (score 1):

you can use an array for storing data, then convert it to an object afterwards !